# Importing a table of real numbers from a text file were data is represeted in Fortran form

Tags: import, string-manipulation

[image]

I'm working on a project that is analyzing seismic displacement data in the above form. It's basically a text file but I could conceivably need to bring in hundreds of files each containing anywhere from 5000 to 15000 values. Below is the best I could come up with. I'm content that it does what I want, but I think it could be better with some export feedback. I'm working in an online notebook and was going to CloudSave or Databin the results. Are there any better approaches to this?

```
(* takes cloud import obj and returns list of values *)
importDataFunction[inputFile_]:= 
  Module[{inputdata, replacedata},
    inputdata = Flatten[StringSplit /@ inputFile[[5;;]]];
    replacedata = StringReplace[#, "E-" -> "*10^-"] &  /@ inputdata;
    Normal[SemanticImportString[#, "Number"]][[1]] &/@ replacedata]
```

Evaluating the above code gives:

[image]

Comment: How is it I've been on the MMA doc site all morning and hadn't come across that page yet? Looks helpful. Just going over it now.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `Import`?  With MMa docs you often have to know that the answer is there and know where to look in order to find it. It is not like using google

Comment: ...I mean that if you are wanting to import files then generally you would first use `Import` to import the file, before attempting a customised import function

Comment: Try Import[file, “Table”]

Comment: In addition to David's code, you might want to add the option `"HeaderLines"-> 4` in order to import the array only and to pack the array it afterwards. something like ``Developer`ToPackedArray@Import[file, "Table", HeaderLines -> 4]``. See alsothe options section of https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.